# How to change "application/octet-stream" to "video/mp4" in HTML5

Tags: html, jsp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
   <head> 
     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">     
   </head> 
   <body> 
     <video id="video" controls src="${maps.url }" height="598" width="782"> 
        Your user agent     does not support the HTML5 Video element. 
     </video> 
   </body> 
</html>
```

This is my code for HTML5 Video. When I run this code in IE 10, the data type is displayed as "application/octet-stream", so it shows an error message. So I know I should switch the type to  "video/mp4".

Does anybody know what I should add to the code to change the type?

Comment: Normally the webserver sets the content-type. Is the file saved with the extension .mp4?

Answer (score 1):

For playing videos using  tag, you can set Content-Type for your source media using 'type' attribute.

eg:

```
    <video poster="movie.jpg" width="320" height="240" controls>
        <source src="movie.mp4" type='video/mp4;'>
            <source src="movie.ogg" type='video/ogg'>
        <p>This is fallback content</p>
    </video>
```

If you don't specify content-type of your source files, browser uses [browser sniffing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Browser_sniffing) to detect and play your source media content. However, your source content maybe alien to the browser(depends on browser), hence it will not be able to play the source file. So, specifying your source and content-type correctly is good practice.

Also, if you are not too sure about your video format, you can specify multiple source elements. In such case, video format that is first recognized by browser is played.

It is a wise idea to include height, width attribute of video. If you set height and width attribute properly, browser will allocate that much space for video when page if loaded. If height and width is not specified, page layout may change during loading of video.

That being said, there are some problems that IE faces while playing content, even if content-type is set properly. Please go thorough [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/thebeebs/archive/2011/07/20/html5-video-not-working-in-ie9-some-tips-to-debug.aspx) blog post, if you are facing the same problem, even after setting proper content type.

You may also want to look at [HTML5_video](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_video) wiki for things like supported format, syntax, et all.